# play 2.4.x current application environment

Tags: java, playframework

Is there any function to return the current working environment of a Play framework application ?
I tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working correctly;

```
String environment = play.api.Play.Mode
```

NOTE: I don't want to use `isDev()` `isProd()` stuff, I want to be able to create custom environments

Comment: `play.api.Play.Mode` is for the scala framework. From your code it looks like you are using Java. Seems that in Java it is `play.Play.Mode` but I could only find it for the 1.x versions.

Comment: @aacanakin I don't think Play lets you create a custom mode (of course you can specify a mode parameter by yourself and do some choices by that parameter, but play will always be running in DEV, TEST or PROD mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlayFramework 2.x supports only 3 modes: Prod, Dev and Test. First is used for production. Second provides more development additions like hotloading just editet classes. The last one is like the second one but with test libraries.

Play 1.x had also `ID`, which was able for using as different environment. For instance  staging or instance of distributed server.

Play 2.x sadly doesn't support `ID`'s anymore. But You can achieve the same effects manually.

Suppose you want to run your application in 'staging' mode.
First you need put configuration file along with basic configuration file, but named as `application.staging.conf`.

Second step is add to `Global.scala` code responsible for managing configuration files, something like this:

```
import java.io.File

import play.api._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader:         ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {
    val env = System.getProperty("environment")
    val envConfig = config ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(s"application.${environment}.conf"))
    super.onLoadConfig(environmentSpecificConfig, path, classloader, mode)
  }
}
```

As you see it reads `environment` value and look at specific configuration file.

The last step is telling play framework which mode it should use. The best way is by starting command:

```
activator run -Denvironment=staging
```

Should works.

Answer (score -3):

In Java it is play.Application.isDev() and isProd() or isTest()

https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/index.html